# Galaxy Note and stock Google Calendar app

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, installation, google-calendar, samsung-galaxy-note

How can I install stock ICS Google Calendar app to a Galaxy Note with original ICS ROM? I found `Calendar.apk` and `CalendarProvider.apk` on the net and tried to install. According to the install these are system apps and I was not able to replace the existing ones that I can't understand because there's no stock calendar on the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has released [Google Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.calendar) as separate app officially on Google Play.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a slightly modified, adapted version on Google Play that works well:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.concentriclivers.calendar